# Update XSLT for XLSX

Tags: excel, xslt, xlsx

I have an old XSLT stylesheet that still works, but only transforms to Excel xls files. I've used ClosedXml to convert grid data to Excel xlsx files and it works great, but I have some formatted Excel documents that are not grids and require some formatting and layout. I would like to convert those old XSLT stylesheets to create the new(er) XLSX format files but only replacing

```
xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
```

with

```
xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/
```

doesn't work.
Has anyone updated an XSLT stylesheet to produce output to Excel xlsx? If yes, please share what you needed to do to accomplish it.
Here's the XSLT stylesheet that I'm trying to convert:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:user="urn:my-scripts" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
    xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
            xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
            xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
      <Styles>
    .. styles
      </Styles>
      <Worksheet ss:Name="name">
        <Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="9" x:FullColumns="1" x:FullRows="1" ss:DefaultRowHeight="13.2">
          <Column ss:Index="2" ss:Width="77"/>
          <Column ss:Index="5" ss:Width="54"/>
          <Column ss:Index="8" ss:Width="178"/>
          <xsl:for-each select="ReportRows/ReportRow">
            <xsl:if test="position()=1">
              <Row>
                <Cell ss:MergeAcross="8" ss:StyleID="s30">
                  <Data ss:Type="String">
                    <xsl:value-of select="SE_Year" /> Title @Lab
                  </Data>
                </Cell>
              </Row>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="Pr_Short_Name != Prev_Project">
              <Row>
                <Cell ss:MergeAcross="8" ss:StyleID="s24" />
              </Row>
              <Row>
                <Cell ss:MergeAcross="8" ss:StyleID="s27">
                  <Data ss:Type="String">
                    <xsl:value-of select="Pr_Long_Name" />
                  </Data>
                </Cell>
              </Row>
              <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
        cells...
              </Row>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="GR_Short_Name != Prev_SampleTypeGroup">
              <Row>
                <Cell ss:MergeAcross="8" ss:StyleID="s31" />
              </Row>
              <Row>
                <Cell ss:MergeAcross="8" ss:StyleID="s32">
                  <Data ss:Type="String">
                    <xsl:value-of select="GR_Short_Name" />
                  </Data>
                </Cell>
              </Row>
            </xsl:if>
            <Row ss:Height="41.4">
        cells...
            </Row>
          </xsl:for-each>
          <Row ss:Height="13.8">
            <Cell ss:MergeAcross="8" ss:MergeDown="1" ss:StyleID="m15419890" />
          </Row>
        </Table>
        <WorksheetOptions xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
          <PageSetup>
            <Header x:Margin="0" />
            <Footer x:Margin="0.3" x:Data="&amp;L&amp;8Form Print Date/Time: &amp;D &amp;T&amp;C&amp;8Page &amp;P of &amp;N" />
            <PageMargins x:Bottom="0.95" x:Left="0.5" x:Right="0.5" x:Top="0.5" />
          </PageSetup>
          <Print>
            <ValidPrinterInfo />
            <Scale>100</Scale>
            <HorizontalResolution>600</HorizontalResolution>
            <VerticalResolution>600</VerticalResolution>
          </Print>
          <Selected />
          <DoNotDisplayGridlines />
          <Panes>
            <Pane>
              <Number>3</Number>
              <ActiveRow>8</ActiveRow>
              <ActiveCol>10</ActiveCol>
            </Pane>
          </Panes>
          <ProtectObjects>False</ProtectObjects>
          <ProtectScenarios>False</ProtectScenarios>
        </WorksheetOptions>
      </Worksheet>
    </Workbook>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Your `XSLT stylesheet` transforms to `XML` in `Microsoft Office Excel 2002 and Excel 2003 XML Format — SpreadsheetML`. That is neither `*.xls` nor `*.xlsx`. It is `*.xml` what `Excel` can import. If opened directly from a file named `*.xls`, `Excel` will thow a warning because of file type mismatch before it imports the `XML`. And a `*.xlsx` file is a `ZIP` archive containing multiple `XML` files related to each other. So stand alone `XSLT stylesheet` transformation cannot create a such.

Comment: Yes, I know that. If you click open it's okay. Excel knows that it's XML and not a true XLS file. Using XSLT creates a formatted XML file, that if opened in Excel, formats a document the way that the users need it to be. This is an old way of exporting a formatted object as a spreadsheet. What I want to do is to be able to open as an XLSX rather than XLS, which I think will open without the warning.

Comment: This XSLT does create a formatted Excel workbook. You WILL get a warning because it's not true Excel but will open without issues (after the warning).
I don't have a problem with this, it works as-is.
WHAT I WOULD LIKE TO KNOW IS.
Has anyone converted an XSLT to work with Excel XLSX? I tried modifying the schema to point to the new version of office but that didn't work.
I don't need help debugging this XSLT, it works but gives a warning.
I think that I could convert if to the current version of Excel it would work without the warning.